# Python functions that calculate first n terms of a given order of Fibonacci sequences

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, algorithm, fibonacci-sequence

I have written two functions that calculate the first `n` terms of a given order `o` of Fibonacci sequence, and return the result as a `list` of `int`s.

from [en.Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers)

> ##### Extension to negative integers
>
> Using \$F_{n−2} = F_n − F_{n−1}\$, one can extend the Fibonacci
> numbers to negative integers. So we get:
>
> ```
>   … −8, 5, −3, 2, −1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, …
> ```
>
> and \$F_{-n} = (−1)^{n+1}F_n\$
>
> ##### Fibonacci numbers of higher order
>
> A Fibonacci sequence of order \$n\$ is an integer sequence in which each
> sequence element is the sum of the previous \$n\$
> elements (with the exception of the first \$n\$
> elements in the sequence).
> The usual Fibonacci numbers are a Fibonacci sequence of order \$2\$.
> The cases \$n = 3\$ and \$n = 4\$ have been thoroughly investigated.
> The number of compositions of nonnegative integers into parts
> that are at most \$n\$ is a Fibonacci sequence of order \$n\$.
> The sequence of the number of strings of \$0\$s and
> \$1\$s of length \$m\$ that contain at most \$n\$ consecutive 0s
> is also a Fibonacci sequence of order \$n\$.
>
> ##### Tribonacci numbers
>
> The tribonacci numbers are like the Fibonacci numbers,
> but instead of starting with two predetermined terms,
> the sequence starts with three predetermined terms
> and each term afterwards is the sum of the preceding three terms.
> The first few tribonacci numbers are:
>
> ```
> 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81, 149, 274, 504, 927, 1705, 3136, 5768, 10609, 19513, 35890, 66012, …
> ```
>
> (sequence [A000073 in the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000073))
>
> ##### Tetranacci numbers
>
> The tetranacci numbers start with four predetermined terms,
> each term afterwards being the sum of the preceding four terms.
> The first few tetranacci numbers are:
>
> ```
> 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 15, 29, 56, 108, 208, 401, 773, 1490, 2872, 5536, 10671, 20569, 39648, 76424, 147312, 283953, 547337, …
> ```
>
> (sequence A000078 in the OEIS)
>
> ---
>
> A **random Fibonacci sequence** can be defined by
> tossing a coin for each position \$n\$ of the sequence and taking
> \$F(n) = F(n−1) + F(n−2)\$ if it lands heads and
> \$F(n) = F(n−1) − F(n−2)\$ if it lands tails.
> Work by Furstenberg and Kesten guarantees that this sequence
> almost surely grows exponentially at a constant rate:
> the constant is independent of the coin tosses
> and was computed in 1999 by Divakar Viswanath.
> It is now known as Viswanath's constant.

The two functions support extension to negative integers and random Fibonacci sequences, and take three parameters: `o: int, n: int, r: int`, `o` means order (of recursion), `n` means number of terms and `r` specifies whether you want the result randomized or not (default `False`).

`o` must be no less than 2. If you input 2 you get Fibonacci, 3 to get Tribonacci, 4 -> Tetranacci, 5 -> Pentanacci, and so on.
`n` must be greater than or equal to `o` (so that you can always tell the order of the sequence and the function never returns a list consisted solely of 0s),
`r` should be always an `int` (`bool` subclasses from `int`).

The following are the functions I want reviewed, I choose the iterative approach, their share the same logic, but I implemented one with a `list`-based approach, the other using variable swapping and variable unpacking:

```py
import random

def h_nacci(o, n, r=False):
    if any(not isinstance(i, int) for i in (n, o, r)):
        raise TypeError('All parameters must be an integer')
    if o < 2 or abs(n) < o:
        raise ValueError('Order is less than 2 or number of terms is less than order')
    positive = True
    if n < 0:
        positive = False
        n = -n
    def worker(n):
        stack = [0] * (o-1) + [1]
        for i in range(n):
            yield stack[0] if positive else (-1)**(i%2+1)*stack[0]
            o_stack = stack
            stack = stack[1:]
            if r and random.randrange(2):
                stack.append(stack[-1] - sum(o_stack[:-1]))
                continue
            stack.append(sum(o_stack))
    series = list(worker(n))
    return series if positive else series[::-1]

def o_nacci(o, n, r=False):
    if any(not isinstance(i, int) for i in (n, o, r)):
        raise TypeError('All parameters must be an integer')
    if o < 2 or abs(n) < o:
        raise ValueError('Order is less than 2 or number of terms is less than order')
    positive = True
    if n < 0:
        positive = False
        n = -n
    def worker(n):
        x, *y, z = [0] * (o-1) + [1]
        for i in range(n):
            yield x if positive else (-1)**(i%2+1)*x
            if r and random.randrange(2):
                x, *y, z = *y, z, z - sum(y) - x
                continue
            x, *y, z = *y, z, x + sum(y) + z
    series = list(worker(n))
    return series if positive else series[::-1]
```

Sample output:

```
In [2]: h_nacci(2, 10)
Out[2]: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]

In [3]: o_nacci(2, 10)
Out[3]: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]

In [4]: h_nacci(3, 10)
Out[4]: [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44]

In [5]: o_nacci(3, 10)
Out[5]: [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44]

In [6]: h_nacci(3, -10)
Out[6]: [44, -24, 13, -7, 4, -2, 1, -1, 0, 0]

In [7]: o_nacci(3, -10)
Out[7]: [44, -24, 13, -7, 4, -2, 1, -1, 0, 0]

In [8]: h_nacci(2, 10, 1)
Out[8]: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, -1, 2]
```

Performance:

```
In [9]: %timeit o_nacci(2, 256)
149 µs ± 3.73 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit h_nacci(2, 256)
123 µs ± 4.25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [11]: %timeit h_nacci(2, -256)
220 µs ± 4.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [12]: %timeit o_nacci(2, -256)
256 µs ± 35.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [13]: %timeit o_nacci(2, 256, 1)
331 µs ± 40 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [14]: %timeit h_nacci(2, 256, 1)
305 µs ± 33.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [15]: %timeit h_nacci(3, 256)
133 µs ± 6.14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [16]: %timeit o_nacci(3, 256)
169 µs ± 4.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

I want to know how to improve their performance, I have implemented every idea I can think of and yet they are still too slow...

Below are some functions posted for comparison only:

```py
def fibonacci(n):  
    positive = True
    if n < 0:
        positive = False
        n = -n              
    def worker(n):         
        a, b = 0, 1
        for i in range(n):
            yield a if positive else (-1)**(i%2+1)*a
            a, b = b, a + b
    series = list(worker(n))
    return series if positive else series[::-1]

def tribonacci(n):
    positive = True
    if n < 0:
        positive = False
        n = -n
    def worker(n):
        a, b, c = 0, 0, 1
        for i in range(n):
            yield a if positive else (-1)**(i%2+1)*a
            a, b, c = b, c, a + b + c
    series = list(worker(n))
    return series if positive else series[::-1]

def random_fibonacci(n):
    def worker(n):
        a, b = 0, 1
        for i in range(n):
            yield a
            c = random.randrange(2)
            if c == 0:
                a, b = b, a + b
            else:
                a, b = b, b - a
    return list(worker(n))
```

```
In [18]: %timeit fibonacci(256)
33.2 µs ± 2.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [19]: %timeit fibonacci(-256)
130 µs ± 5.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [20]: %timeit tribonacci(256)
45.2 µs ± 5.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [21]: %timeit tribonacci(-256)
148 µs ± 4.27 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [22]: %timeit random_fibonacci(256)
210 µs ± 5.57 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

How can I implement the same idea more efficiently? How can the two big functions be optimized further?

Comment: By the way, a series extending to the left shouldn't have randomized signs, the negative n and truthy r were supposed to be exclusive to each other, I could just add some checks and throw an exception if they appear at the same call, but decided against editting the code.

Comment: How do you use the results, what is the acid test telling *fast enough* from `still too slow`? (microbench source code welcome…) What about *higher* orders - 9, 42, 1984?

Comment: @greybeard I use these functions in my super hacky and convoluted script to encode plain text and I need them to be fast, beyond this I can't divulge any more information.

Comment: Rosetta stone: [Python generator & anamorphic](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_n-step_number_sequences#Python:_Generator)

Comment: Generally, with non-compiled environments (did you give PyPy&Cython a spin?), move conditional execution as far out as you can. (FWIW, my best unrolled stabs at 2&3-term Fibonacci-like were just 5&3 time faster than `h_nacci`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see much in terms of ways to improve this. A deque (from collections) is a little faster than a list for adding to both ends:

```
def deque_nacci(o, n, r=False):
    if any(not isinstance(i, int) for i in (n, o, r)):
        raise TypeError('All parameters must be an integer')
    if o < 2 or abs(n) < o:
        raise ValueError('Order is less than 2 or number of terms is less than order')
    positive = True
    if n < 0:
        positive = False
        n = -n
    def worker(n):
        stack = deque([0] * (o-1) + [1])
        for i in range(n):
            if r and random.randrange(2):
                last = stack.pop()
                new_last = last - sum(stack)
                stack.append(last)
                stack.append(new_last)
            else:
                stack.append(sum(stack))
            yield stack.popleft() if positive else (-1)**(i%2+1)*stack.popleft()

    series = list(worker(n))
    return series if positive else series[::-1]
```

That gives a slight improvement:

[image: benchmarks]

Comment: Not much improvement in performance, still improvement nonetheless.